# flex tile list transparent image showing with a white background

Tags: apache-flex, image, tilelist

I have a tile list that loads images from a folder within the app.

When i load images with a transparent background it gives the image a white background is there any way to get the image to be transparent?

Thanks!

I'm adding the images from a list of images i loop through

```
var y:Image = new Image(); 
y.height = 100;
y.width = 100;
y.id =  list[i].MID;
y.source = (list[i].vchImagePath);
y.name = (list[i].vchName); 
theArray.addItem(y);
```

Comment: the images are they PNG or other extention

Comment: what method are you using to load image ? do you convert them to bitmapdata

Comment: I have added the code in the question. Thanks!

Comment: i don't see where the problem come from maybe you should add maintainAspectRatio = false; or remove width & height

Answer (score 0):

If you use an itemRenderer in your list, you can set the autoDrawBackground property to false.

Dany